# Extracting Image from latex

Tags: graphics

I want to show chemical reactions on a website so i want to just get image from LaTeX code.
I know how to add images to latex but don't know how to get image from LaTeX.

Example
I want to get images of

```
\chemname{\chemfig{CH_3-CH(-[2]CH_3)-CH_2-Cl}}{Isobutyl chloride}
```

which look like this 
[image]

Comment: Hi, i think the `standalone` class will do exactly what you want. :-)

Comment: @Johannes_B Would you mind explaining abit with details ? i don't get what you are saying :(

Comment: didn't you just do exactly that to ask this question?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle yes but that image is from google :P .

Comment: @DavidCarlisle or i can make pdf from latexcode and take the screenshot and post here. but is there any option that directly give images on compiling or nearly 1 step process ?

Comment: screenshot is what I do for posting here but standalone class will make a page closely cropped to the one page content so just make a document  that only has your formula

Comment: @DavidCarlisle cann't get you . Do you mean that i should also do screenshot ? or that standalone will generate 1 page image? is there any guide of using standalone?

Comment: with standalone you'll get a pdf cropped to the formula, you can use that directly as an image or use any convertor to convert the pdf to png or whatever you need. I see Johannes has given an example. for any package `texdoc standalone` gives the documentation.

Comment: related [changing font of wordpress quick latex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/252528)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Package `preview` was written for this purpose (to generate PNG images to be included in the emacs editor).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

% A fixed `\chemname`, which takes the width of the name into account
\newcommand*{\ChemName}[2]{%
  \begingroup
    \sbox0{#1}%
    \sbox2{#2}%
    \ifdim\wd2>\wd0 %
      \leavevmode
      \hbox to \wd2{\hss\chemname{#1}{#2}\hss}%
    \else
      \chemname{#1}{#2}%
    \fi
  \endgroup
}

\usepackage[active, tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewMacro[[!!]\chemname
\PreviewMacro[!]\chemfig
\PreviewMacro[!!]\ChemName

\begin{document}
\chemname{\chemfig{CH_3-CH(-[2]CH_3)-CH_2-Cl}}{Isobutyl chloride}
\chemfig{R-C(-[:-30]OH)=[:30]O}
\ChemName{\chemfig{CH_3CH_2Cl}}{Ethyl Chlorid}
\end{document}
```

The document catches `\chemname` and `\chemfig` and generates two pages with tight bounding boxes. The PDF file can then be converted to bitmaps by ImageMagick's `convert` or Ghostscript, for example.

```
convert -density 300 test.pdf test-%02.png
```

Generates `test-00.png`, `test-01.png`, and `test-02.png`:

> [image: test-01.png]

> [image: test-02.png]

> [image: test-03.png]

Package `preview` takes the bounding box as reported from TeX. If a macro `\chemname` prints outside the box, when the name is longer than the formula, then the result is cropped. Macro `\ChemName` measures the two widths and increases the bounding box if necessary.

Comment: when i try convert it says failed to execute command gswin32c.exe like that??

Comment: any solutions of this problem?

Comment: @user80946 You have installed ghostscript?

Comment: I have installed imagemagicks binaries

Comment: should i need to install ghostscript as well?

Comment: @user80946 Yes, for some conversions, ImageMagick uses other programs, thus ghostscript is needed as well.

Comment: Man installing ghostscript worked but theere is a problem some part are chopped off . see this  : http://i.imgur.com/E57qtpB.png?1

Comment: @user80946 See updated answer.

Comment: I used the code as shown in answer but the result is still same ? haven't you changed the code in updated answer? When i add \chemname{\chemfig{C(-[:90]H)(-[:270]Cl)(-[:180]H)-Cl}}{Methylene chloride} some part is chooped off :(

Comment: @user80946 Missing line for Ethyl Chlorid added, which uses `\ChemName` instead of `\chemname`.

Comment: now it worked great :)

Answer (score 0):

Make a very minimal tex-file in which just the `chemfig` code is.

```
% this is file isobutylChloride
\chemfig{CH_3-CH(-[2]CH_3)-CH_2-Cl}
\endinput
```

Now, input that file in a `standalone` document and compile it with the `-shell-escape` flag. A png file will be created on the fly, a conversion program is needed to be installed, though.

```
\documentclass[convert=true]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\input{isobutylChloride}
\end{document}
```

In your real (big) document, you can include the high-quality pdf, the compilation will be faster as well.

There are other options to the `standalone` class, every little detail is available in the package documentation.

Comment: It creates pdf file ? how to get images?

Comment: From the answer: *A png file will be created on the fly, a conversion program is needed to be installed, though.*

Comment: is it necessary to create one more file here isobutylChloride ..isn't it possible to do all things in same file ?

Comment: Yes, see Heikos answer.

Comment: I am guessing that you have a huge document. Having the definition *outside* seems to be the best you can do. You could also use tikzexternalize, that catches every changes to your tikz-pictures automatically. Transformation to png would be done by hand then. As we don't have much information about your setup, this is the best i can tell.