# changing font of wordpress quick latex

Tags: fonts

The font of word press quick latex looks so light and not so good. Is it possible to change the font a bit dark and a bit cool?

and i am writing chemical reaction so i must use wp quick latex as i have not found any other plugin that writes chemical reaction on word press on fly.

I want to show chemical reaction but it appears so dim ,blurry and irregular color like this .

[image]
Thanks.

But when i see pdf it looks so better than that by wp quick latex enter image description here
[image]

Comment: related [Extracting Image from latex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/252519)

Comment: If it is the image rendering that QuickLaTeX uses which bothers you then go to the QuickLaTeX settings > System and change *Image format* into *Auto* or *SVG*.

Comment: @clemens I mean the second image is taken from PDF after compiling and first image is taken from wp quick latex. I wonder why second looks too much better but first one looks very bad :( . i have no problem using png or svg .

Comment: @user80946 from [the QuickLaTeX homepage](http://www.holoborodko.com/pavel/quicklatex/): »Rendering into vector image format SVG, which means formulas are always crisp and preserve high-resolution quality regardless of zooming factor in the browser. Automatic detection of browser capabilities and silent fall back to raster PNG images for older browsers. This is essential for modern high-dpi screens (Retina, Super Amoled, etc.)«

Comment: @clemens finally a big thanks .. It was problem of PNG that it renders very badly . I find no problem in SVG . However i have a lot of question like showing reaction on wp quick latex. Should i post or directly discuss with you ?

Comment: If this isn't about QuickLaTeX but about usage of `chemfig` then I'd suggest to [post new questions](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) for particular questions including a useful minimal working example that people can use to test (even if they haven't any QuickLaTeX)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since QuickLaTeX allows a custom preamble you can simply add a font package, just like you would in a LaTeX document:

```
[latex]
[preamble]
\usepackage{chemfig}
[/preamble]
\chemname{\chemfig{CH_3-CH(-[2]CH_3)-CH_2-Cl}}{Isobutyl chloride}
[/latex]

[latex]
[preamble]
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{chemfig}
[/preamble]
\chemname{\chemfig{CH_3-CH(-[2]CH_3)-CH_2-Cl}}{Isobutyl chloride}
[/latex]


[latex]
[preamble]
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{chemfig}
[/preamble]
\chemname{\chemfig{CH_3-CH(-[2]CH_3)-CH_2-Cl}}{Isobutyl chloride}
[/latex]
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

If you want this for all QuickLaTeX uses on your blog then add the font packages to the global QuickLaTeX preamble (WP QuickLaTeX > Advanced) without the `[preamble]`/`[/preamble]` shortcode. (The short code is meant to be used in posts for locally overwriting the global preamble. (There's also `[+preamble]`/`[/preamble]` for use in post to add stuff to the global preamble locally.)

If it is only the rendering of the images: go to the QuickLaTeX settings *System* and change the image format from *PNG* into *SVG* or – preferably – into *Auto*. Quote from [the QuickLaTeX homepage](http://www.holoborodko.com/pavel/quicklatex/):

> Rendering into vector image format SVG, which means formulas are
>   always crisp and preserve high-resolution quality regardless of
>   zooming factor in the browser. Automatic detection of browser
>   capabilities and silent fall back to raster PNG images for older
>   browsers. This is essential for modern high-dpi screens (Retina, Super
>   Amoled, etc.)

Comment: is it possible to get all latex code in 3rd form always . So that i should not write \usepackage .. i have to nearly write 100 reaction and it may kill me:(

Comment: @user80946 The QuickLaTeX plugin also also has a global preamble which is then active for the whole WordPress site. Go to QuickLaTeX settings > Advanced

Comment: it means i these \usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{chemfig} or i should add premble as well? and what preamble means?

Comment: @user80946 Have you ever even written a LaTeX document? The preamble is the part between `\documentclass` and `\begin{document}`. It is the part of a document where packages a loaded, setup is done, custom macros are defined, …

Comment: @user80946 the `[preamble]` short code is used in a post to add custom preamble settings for the current LaTeX code and it overwrites whatever settings you have in the global QuickLaTeX preamble. The shortcode `[+preamble]` adds its settings to the global preamble.

Comment: what should i write for global premable .  I added this  in wp quick latex advanced [preamble]
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{chemfig}
[/preamble] and i posted this in new post [latex]
\chemname{\chemfig{CH_3-CH(-[2]CH_3)-CH_2-Cl}}{Isobutyl chloride}
[/latex] . Now it is showing  *** QuickLaTeX cannot compile formula:
*** Error message:
Missing number, treated as zero.
leading text: [preamble]

Comment: @user80946 you need to remove `[preamble]` and `[/preamble]` from the global preamble. they're only meant to be used in posts

Comment: i added screenshot is it possible to make like that .. yeah you did better but can we make like second screen shot of post that i added?

Comment: @user80946 I didn't make screenshots: I downloaded the PNG files which QuickLaTeX integrated into the post. Anyway, see my comment to your question.